# Check if object is null - performance differences

Tags: c#, performance, ants

I just discovered a weird behaviour in my application while doing a perfomance analysis with ANTS Performance Profiler:

```
public void set_SelectedObject(object value)
{
    if (value == null) //65ms
    {
       //do anything
    }
}
```

This check takes 65ms whereas other checks if objects are null take less than 0,Xms.
What could be the reason for this? I thought a null-check is always constant no matter what value is passed - Does it depend on the size of my object?

Comment: It shouldn't. I think either that's not your actual code, or you're misinterpreting the profiler's results. Are you sure it's not the *whole* method that's taking 65ms to execute?

Comment: What is the hit count? Might be a huge number?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What I let out was the fact, that this method is "generated" by Reflector. The class is a Grid in DevExpress. Might it be that the reflector didn't catch a PropertyChangedEvent or some other dependencies? And the hit count is 4, but I already divided the time through this value (in fact it was 258ms in total)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast-iron rule for profilers is that absolute results aren't accurate or important. They are only useful as a comparison tool - i.e. is my code faster with or without change X? That said, 65ms is still a substantial chunk of time that shouldn't appear as a result of profiler variance, unless the profiler is really bad.

I haven't used the C# ANTS profiler, I would be amazed if it gave you a timing for single line of code like that. Are you sure it's not the time to execute the entire block surrounded by the if-statement?

If it is giving you a time for just that line, that implies a function call is being made - i.e. an operator overload on the value class.

Comment: you're right, the time is shown in the line of the equasion, but I guess this is showing the time for the whole if-else statement...

Answer (score 2):

It's nonsense. Checking the value against null will always have similar impact on your performance. It may take 65 ms, because a reference you're sending to the method may actually be a null, which triggers the logic inside your `if` statement or the oposite - there's some heavy logic that's being fired, when the object is not a null.

The only theoretical reason I could imagine is that you use an overloaded == operator for some class, but it'd have to be really poor piece of code if it wouldn't check for null first.

Comment: Actually my method is "generated" by Reflector. The original method is "Set_Selected_Object" in DevExpress-XtraVerticalGrid. I guess they fire an event if the value is set...

Comment: Your theoretical reason is not true. `==` operator can't be overloaded for `System.Object`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You are right. The operator'd have to be a virtual method, which obviously won't be implemented this way, since it's static.